# Fastest way to combine many JSON files that don't fit in memory

Tags: python, json, performance, memory

I have about 100,000 JSON files with this structure:

```
{'images': [<list of dicts>],
 'annotations': [<list of dicts>],
 'videos': [<list of dicts>]}
```

Each JSON varies in size, but the average is about 2MB. I have a lot of RAM (488GB), but still seem to only fit about 70% of these into memory.

What would be the fastest way in Python to combine these into a single JSON file (with the same three keys, where the lists are combined into single large lists)?

---

I considered looping through all of them 3x (one loop for each key) and appending to a file, but this would be very slow. I'm unsure if there exists a better way.

Here's how I attempted to load them all at once (which slows down and then fails before completing):

```
from glob import glob
import json
from tqdm import tqdm

full = {
    'videos': [],
    'images': [],
    'annotations': []
}

for fp in tqdm(glob('coco_parts/*.json')):
    with open(fp, 'r') as f:
        single = json.load(f)
        full['videos'] += single['videos']
        full['images'] += single['images']
        full['annotations'] += single['annotations']
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with a 200 GB JSON file? Are you sure you don’t want to rather use a database?

Comment: I think the JSON will end up around 150GB (may have got my average off a bit). The format is a COCO JSON file [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0312.pdf] which will be used to train an object detection deep learning model. It needs to be loaded into memory to prevent data loading bottlenecks in model training.

Comment: @Sylvaus Hi, thanks for your answer. This was my first idea, but I'd need to read each json 3x right? I'm very curious if there's a faster way, since that would take approximately 4hrs on my system.

Comment: JSON is a data transport mechanism. It should be expanded into whatever structure is needed by the rest of your system. Does COCO have a preferred on-disk format? Then convert to that. There are lots of formats like bigtable, parquet, etc... that are more compact.

Comment: Sorry I read your edit too late: The question I have now is: if you cannot have all that data in RAM, how do you expect to read this file for processing ?

Comment: The models and dataloaders I'm currently working with assume a single COCO file, and modifying all that will be too time prohibitive. Once the file is created it will fit in memory, but I can't seem to load it as pieces. I assume there's some overhead for each file.

Comment: What is the dataloaders input type ? a file handle ? a file path ?

Comment: A file path: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/pycocotools/coco.py#L71

Comment: You could try a divide and conquer approach: start by merging a 1000 at a time that will give you a resulting 100 json that you may be able to merge easily

Comment: You're doing something wrong if you can't do this with that much memory. Please [edit] your question and show your attempt that's running out of memory.

Comment: Also could you share the code you used to load all the JSON and that didn't work ? To see if an optimization could be done there

Comment: Edited with attempt that's running out of memory

Comment: What framework are you using to train the object detection model? If it is tensorflow, you should use a `tf.data.Dataset` for this. If pytorch, use `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. With either of these methods, you do not have to load the entire dataset into memory.

Comment: @jakub The entire dataset isn't loaded into memory (in terms of images) but the metadata is. I'm subclassing torch.utils.data.Dataset. Their CocoDetection class does nearly the same thing (I don't use this because I have additional fields): https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/coco.html#CocoDetection

Comment: Shouldn't it be extend instead of append in your attempt ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have copied/pasted. It's += instead of append.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I will leave this here as an answer.

The fact that you can't store these files in memory although this shouldn't be a problem for your pc *may* be due to the overhead added by the python objects you're using:

> {'images': [<list of dicts>],

> 'annotations': [<list of dicts>],

> 'videos': [<list of dicts>]}

One idea may be to switch to using something else like a single string (preserving the correct JSON structure) or using pandas/numpy just like these articles suggest: [article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-object-memory/), [article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-integers-memory/).